# How to prove the possibilities of inequality？

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose $a_{i}>0$, and $b_{i}=0$ or $1$，obviously we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}b_{i})\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i},$$
and set ${b_{i}}$ have $2^n$ possibilities in all，while if
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}b_{i})\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}$$
how to prove set ${b_{i}}$ have at least  $2^{n-1}$ possibilities?

Comment: Is it true? If $n=2$, the choices $(1,1)$, and one of $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ for the value of $(b_1, b_2)$ seem to violate the inequality. So I'd guess that we have $2=2^2-2$ and not $3=2^2-1$ possibilities.

Comment: sorry , I have edited it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that $2^{n-1}$ is half of $2^n$ and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}b_{i}) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}(1-b_{i}))=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}$$
implies
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}b_{i})\leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}\quad
\text{OR}\quad \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_{i}(1-b_{i}))\leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}.$$

Comment: I love this! :)